# how to use image transition from dynamically created imageview to activity

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

In my project, all image is being displayed in a layout (as container) by image view (i am not using list view or recycler view here) which is created dynamically. when user clicks on this image view, it starts another activity and display the image in bigger image view. It is working fine, but here i want image transition from dynamically created image view to activity image view. I have tried so many, but not successful yet. I need some clarification here:
1. Is it possible to do like that, at all?
2. where to set the transition name of dynamically created image view?
3. should i transfer the image data in Bitmap form or only file url to the another activity??

Answer (score 0):

```
    In your Style add this line  <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

    In ImageView  required attr is android:transitionName="profile"


    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
      android:transitionName="profile"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="160dp" />

    Pass this in your  Activity 

      Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
      // Pass data object in the bundle and populate details activity.
      intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT, contact);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {      ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
      makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View)ivProfile, "profile");
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }else{
      startActivity(intent)
    }    
    add this  attr in second activity ImageView also android:transitionName="profile"
```

Comment: i think you have misinterpreted my question. In first activity ImageView is being created in runtime, so it is not working like activity to activity image transition.